# Can a formula with only unique variables be an intuitionistic tautology?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, intuitionistic-logic

Consider intuitionistic propositional formulae, using only the connective "$\rightarrow$"  <s>and absurdity</s> .
Can there exist a formula such that it is a theorem/tautology and every pair of variables contained in it, is a pair of different variables?

Comment: What about e.g. $\bot\to x$?

Comment: You are correct, I did not think about that. Thank you, I will remove absurdity from the question.

Comment: Do you mean that no variables are repeated? I.e. any variable that occurs in the formula only occurs once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prove this using the [topological semantics for intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Heyting_algebra_semantics).

Our chosen topological space is $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard topology. The open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the truth values and $\mathbb{R}$ itself is the sole designated truth value. If you do this, you can construct explicit truth values for all of the variables in a well-formed formula that make the formula have a non-designated truth value.

Next I'll define a notion of a *covariant position* and a *contravariant position*.

In the well-formed formula, $a \to b$, $a$ is a contravariant position and $b$ is a covariant position.

In the well-formed formula $(a \to b) \to c$, $b$ is a contravariant position and $a$ and $c$ are covariant positions.

A position is covariant if and only if it is the antecedent of an even number of conditionals.

Consider a well-formed formula $\varphi$ with no repeated variable symbols. Let $A$ be the variables that appear covariantly and $B$ be the variables that appear contravariantly. Note that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and their union is all the variables of $\varphi$.

Consider a variable $x$ that appears in $\varphi$.

If $x$ is in $A$, then give $x$ the truth value $\varnothing$.

If $x$ is in $B$, then give $x$ the truth value $\mathbb{R}$.

$\varphi$ will thus have the truth value $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 3):

No such formula is a tautology. Since the arguments to the outermost $\implies$ are independent, there is always a model where the antecedent is true and the consequent is false.

Let's do an example. Consider the sentence
$$ (a\implies b) \implies (c \implies (d \implies e)). $$
Because they share no variables, we can easily make $a\implies b$ true while $c \implies (d\implies e)$ is false. Consider any assignment with $a$ and $e$ false, and $c$ and $d$ true. Such an assignment gives the formula the form $T \implies F$, so it can't be a tautology.

Comment: This is really an inductive argument, right? To find an assignment making $\varphi\implies \psi$ false, you need to find an assignment making $\psi$ false (which is possible by induction). It's interesting to note from unwinding this inductive argument that you can always set the right-most variable to false and all others to true.

Comment: That's right, to prove it formally, you have to induct on the height of the sentence's syntax tree.